# How to get count for database query in Accumulo

Tags: java, accumulo

**Every database** I've ever seen has a method for retrieving the count of the query prior to actually executing it. But I can't figure how to do this simple task in Accumulo.

Just for clarity, I want the Accumulo analog of this [Mongo feature](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/).

I checked the [Scanner apidocs](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.4/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/Scanner.html) but I can't find anything. I'm using Java but answers for other languages would be greatly helpful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accumulo is a lower-level application than a traditional RDBMS. It is based on [Google's Big Table](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) and not like a relational database. It's more accurately described as a *massive parallel sorted map* than a *database*.

It is designed to do different kinds of tasks than a relational database, and its focus is on *big data*.

To achieve the equivalent of the MongoDB feature you mentioned in Accumulo (to get a count of the size of an arbitrary query's result set), you can write a server-side [Iterator](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/accumulo_user_manual.html#_iterators) which returns counts from each server, which can be summed on the client side to get a total. If you can anticipate your queries, you can also create an index which keeps track of counts during the ingest of your data.

Creating custom `Iterators` is an advanced activity. Typically, there are important trade-offs (time/space/consistency/convenience) to implementing something as seemingly simple as a count of a result set, so proceed with caution. I would recommend consulting the user [mailing list](https://accumulo.apache.org/mailing_list.html) for information and advice.

Comment: Thank you for the informative response, it wasn't exactly the answer I was hoping for but it helps.

Comment: A colleague and I were discussing one way to stage the resultset of a query (to get counts and other data) without bringing back the whole thing yet, and we came up with an idea. It's somewhat complicated, but I'm sure we can discuss on the mailing lists. In short:
1. Clone a table
2. Perform the query through compaction iterators
3. Truncate to the desired row range bounds
Result: Your entire query in a new table, with the exact count (entries, not rows) in the metadata for retrieval.